# IIS asmx website strange caching behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, caching, asmx

I have noticed some strange behavior in IIS 
I think that is probably related to some cache in IIS

I have an api website and there is a method for login in

```
http://myapi.loc/api/login.asmx/GetSessionID?userId=qqqqqq&password=wwwwww&company=eeeeee&plant=rrrrrr&pool=tttttt
```

Today one of the users had their password expired. so the api was giving an error that password is expired. that is correct.

i have changed the password for this user via admin interface.
after that i've tried to login with new password

```
http://myapi.loc/api/login.asmx/GetSessionID?userId=qqqqqq&password=newpassword&company=eeeeee&plant=rrrrrr&pool=tttttt
```

and there still was error that password is expired. this is strange.
after that i've opened C# code for this method. added a space and saved the file.
after this user logged in successfully. this is very strange.

so i was thinking that iis caches request or code somehow?
this is not the only method that is behaving like this
could you tell me what may cause this strange behavior and how to fix it?

web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings/>
    <client/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" /> 
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Has the user tried flushing their DNS and browser cache? Also, with HTTP the credentials are being sent as clear text...

Comment: Have you configured Output Caching in IIS?  If there is, it is related to the server cache, if not, it may be caused by your code.